# Use Fourier and Arial Narrow fonts in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I want to use Fourier as default font for my document and Arial Narrow for my tables. This has meant that I would need to compile in XeLaTeX with the following MWE:

```
%\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl, booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Heuristica} % substitute for fourier
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial Narrow}

\begin{document}

My report discusses ...

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \sffamily
  \centering
  \onehalfspacing
    \begin{tabular}{crr}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{data 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{data 2}} \\
    \textbf{data 1} & 1 & -0.30 \\
    \textbf{data 2} & -0.30 & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \caption{massive correlation matrix for my data, use Arial Narrow.}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

I can use Fourier in pdfLaTeX and Arial Narrow in XeLaTeX, but not both fonts in XeLaTeX (or pdfLaTeX). When I compile in Miktex, I get an error in the log file:

```
Error 1 (driver return code) generating output;
file test.pdf may not be valid.
```

and no pdf is generated.

Comment: ? your document already contains \setmainfont{Heuristica}, so where is the problem?

Comment: You can use legacy fonts in xelatex and lualatex (if the font definition files are OK, and if you know the NFSS family name): e.g., `\usefont{T1}{futs}{m}{n}` after begin{document}. Why not use truetype/opentype fonts, though?

Comment: @ Cicada .. It doesn't necessarily have to be Arial Narrow, but I would prefer to use a narrow sans serif font for my table entries.